# make a dictionary from lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following lists.

```
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

value1 = [1,2]
value2 = [10,20]
value3 = [100,200]
```

How can I get the result like `[{"key1":1, "key2":10, "key3":100},{"key1":2, "key2":20, "key3":200}]` using python?

I tried for loops but I couldn't find any solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly did you try? Looping is a good approach.

Comment: On a more general note, if your three variables play similar roles, they should be included in a common structure (dict, list ...) rather than being related by similar names.

Comment: @navneethc I have tried various for loop and also for loop inside for loop. But each time I couldn't get exact result.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille I noted your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to first `zip` your values elementwise, then create dictionaries by zipping those against your keys.

```
>>> [dict(zip(keys, i)) for i in zip(value1, value2, value3)]
[{'key1': 1, 'key2': 10, 'key3': 100}, {'key1': 2, 'key2': 20, 'key3': 200}]
```

Comment: Sure, it gets the job done for the OP for the example posted, but IMHO it's too terse an answer for someone ostensibly having trouble with for loops.

Comment: @navneethc So I should avoid providing a pythonic answer even though it is concise and correct? If the OP has any questions about this solution they are free to ask follow-up questions. No reason to make assumptions about what other people know, or want to learn about. If they are unfamiliar with list comprehensions, now is great time to learn about them.

Comment: They have stated that couldn't proceed anywhere with for loops. It's not unreasonable to assume that they have not encountered the zip function and comprehensions. Moreover I personally consider an answer more useful when it not just answer's the OP's question but also clarifies the issue for others, who too may not be aware of the aforementioned topics, in the future. (That's kind of the reason for SO's existence, in a way.) What I would suggest in way of improving the answer would have been to include brief explanations of the "newer" bits or at least provide links to explanatory material.

Comment: That said, what was unreasonable to assume was that I somehow said that you should avoid providing a pythonic answer.

Comment: @Cory Kramer Thank you for your answer. I didn't have to use the "zip". I will learn usage of "zip". It seems more easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using for loop. Like this

```
keys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

value1 = [1,2]
value2 = [10,20]
value3 = [100,200]
values = [value1, value2, value3]
output = [{}, {}]

for i in range(len(keys)):
    output[0][keys[i]] = values[i][0]
    output[1][keys[i]] = values[i][1]

print(output)
```

**Output**

```
[{'key1': 1, 'key2': 10, 'key3': 100}, {'key1': 2, 'key2': 20, 'key3': 200}]
```

Comment: Actually I tried to reach your solution. When I look my tries, I was very close but I missed  `output = [{}, {}]` Thank you.